# RSA private key?

Tags: rsa

I recently solved a stage in a challenge where I received 5 very large integers with character labels.  I think they are components of an RSA key but I am a nooby to crypto and not sure.

I have `p, q, dp, dq` and `c`.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like RSA CRT; you have everything for last line of step 1 then step 2 [here](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/crt_rsa.html).

Comment: @fgrieu Any tools to perform those calculations?  I can't get my computer to accurately compute qinv, it keeps rounding 1/q to 0

Comment: Look at Sage <https://www.sagemath.org/>

Answer (score 1):

> I can't get my computer to accurately compute qinv, it keeps rounding
>   $1/q$ to 0

This is because you are using real-valued division. You want $q_{\mathit{inv}}=q^{-1}\bmod p$, i.e. the integer $q_{\mathit{inv}}$ such that $q\cdot q_{\mathit{inv}}\bmod p=1$. If you are using `sagemath`, then you can use the built-in `inverse_mod(q,p)` function to make the above computation.

> I think they are components of an RSA key but I am a nooby to crypto
>   and not sure. I have `p, q, dp, dq` and `c`.

As pointed out by fgrieu in the comments, [this resource](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/crt_rsa.html) details how to decrypt, given these values, as you are in the last line of the first step. I shall reproduce the (computationally relevant) contents for your convenience.

1. Compute $q_{\mathit{inv}}=(1/q)=q^{-1}\bmod p$, e.g. using `inverse_mod`
2. Compute $m_1=c^{d_p}\bmod p$, e.g. using `pow(c,dp,p)`
3. Compute $m_2=c^{d_q}\bmod q$
4. Compute $h=q_{\mathit{inv}}\cdot (m_1-m_2)\bmod p$
5. Recover $m=m_2+h\cdot q$

Comment: @DesertSands Note the $dp$ and $dq$ are redundant, you can get message $m$ just with knowing $p$, $q$, public exponent $e$ and cipher $c$. For this first compute $\phi = (p-1)(q-1)$, and then compute $d$ by $d = e^{-1} \pmod \phi $ and then $m = c ^{d} \pmod n$, whete $n = pq$.